# VB.NET - Accessing the Value of a Combobox Created at Runtime in a Button Click Event

Tags: vb.net

I have dynamically created comboboxes. I can work with them fine in the subroutine in which they were created (the on load event). However, if I try to access the values in a different subroutine, a button click event, I get a "'ComboBox1' is not declared" error. How can I access the value of a dynamically created combobox, in this case ComboBox1, from a button click event?

Comment: Can you show us how you are creating them?

Comment: thisComboBox.Location = New Point(375, ComboBoxVertLoc)
            thisComboBox.Size = New Size(200, 23)... Me.Controls.Add(thisComboBox)

Comment: So, assuming you've got some sort of indication of your target combo box in the button click event such as the combobox name, it's just a case of finding the correct combo in forms control collection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=net-5.0

Comment: You have to find dynamically created `combobox` using `Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(object.Controls.Find("controlName",False)(0), ComboBox)`. Now You can access, get, selected item from `cb`. I assume You set `name` (`id`) for each dynamically created `combobox`. Please, provide code how you create dynamically comboboxes and how you try to access/get selected item (from that other sub).

Answer (score 0):

There is simple example of dynamically creating `combobox` and how to get selected item.
Comments are in code :

```
     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cb As New ComboBox
        'create array of string which we will store into combobox
        Dim ss As String() = {"one", "two", "three", "four"}
        cb.DataSource = ss
        cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        cb.Size = New Size(200, 23)
        cb.Location = New Point(10, 100)
        cb.Name = "cb1" 'very important to set name (id) of dynamically created combobox
        Me.Controls.Add(cb) 'add dynamically created combobox on form
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'find dynamically created combobox with id/name od "cb1"
        'It's important to set (0) after Me.Controls.Find - that's mean you'll "take" first combobox with id named "cb1"
        Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("cb1", False)(0), ComboBox)
        'show value of selected item
        MsgBox(cb.SelectedItem.ToString)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
  Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to name the combobox. It works fine now. Thank you!